# Writing/Printing Table Contents for Multi-Page Table

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am looking to read the table of inmates at a jail 
http://www.showmeboone.com/sheriff/jailresidents/

And print each entry per row separated by a column (for eventually writing to a CSV).

I want to get the Name,City,Age etc followed by the href link to the "details" button.

I've parsed tables before, but this seems to be more complicated. I've modified code which I put here that has worked in the past, but it's not printing the right information at all.

I've been investigating the source code of the page to try to find the class of the tables and td's to use, but I'm not too skilled with that and can't find it, once I get that, I'll look into how to use BeautifulSoup to specify a specific class for the td/tables.

```
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

table = soup.table
table = soup.find('table')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr') 

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    for i in row:
        print(i, end=",")
```

I want, in the end, to create CSV file for this table with it looking like this (excluding the links to the more details).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvdSN.jpg

Comment: What results are you getting right now?

Comment: Using jlaur's helpful code, I'm currently getting an excel file containing all the info I need, but only from the first page of inmates. Not entirely sure how to get data from all 5 pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues at play here.

For starters you seem to be hitting the wrong URL. Secondly you need to set a User-Agent in your request - otherwise this site returns no data at all and status code 500. Thirdly: There are 14 tables on this page. You need to select the right one.

I suggest starting like this:

```
# when I hit the url given by you it redirects to the one below
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# you can set the number of rows to be returned with a max_rows-paramter
url = 'https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/SH01_MP.I00290s?max_rows=1000'

# set user-agent
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla Firefox 50.0'}

# collect data
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

# so do some inspection with the dev tools
# the table you need is has these classes
# "collapse data-table shadow responsive"
# use css-selector to grab that one particular table
table = soup.select_one('table.collapse.data-table.shadow.responsive')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
# continue extracting data....
```

So the first 3 rows doesn't contain data. The data you're interested actually resembles dictionaries, as it has an attribute ('data-sh'), that hold the key for the content in the td. This is true for all tds but the one containing the href. For this one td the attribute == "". So an easy logic to extract the data would be something like this:

```
base_url = "https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/"
user_list = []
for row in table_rows[3:]:
    tds = row.find_all('td')
    user_dict = {}
    for td in tds:
        key = td.get('data-th')
        value = td.get_text().strip()
        # if key == "", the td contains the href
        if key == "":
            key = "link"
            value = base_url + td.find('a').get('href')

        user_dict[key] = value
    user_list.append(user_dict)
```

That'll yield a list of dicts containing all the data you need. Dicts export easily using the CSV-module or using pandas

If pandas is your choise you only need to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(user_list)
df.to_excel("outfile.xlsx", encoding="utf-8", index=False)
```

Hope that helps you further on.

Comment: Dude this is awesome! You have no idea how much this is teaching me about BeautifulSoup. Thank you so much! Something I'm trying to figure out right now is how to include all five pages of the inmate log in the outfile. Any clue? The button seems to be javascript and I'm not sure how to return all entries from it

Comment: Glad to help. So the paging thing is easily done but using a param, but that kinda not related to your question here. But the site actually responds to a max_rows-parameter, so if it's just about getting the data set it to 1000 and you're in the clear - no need for paging. I've updated the answer. If it helps you out, please accept it and close the question.

Comment: By the way if you don't accept answers you'll have a hard time getting help again. That's how SO works.

Comment: Sorry man! Appreciate the help, I just figured out how to accept it. Thanks again!